# Update Parent object record from multiple Child records?

Tags: process-builder, childrelationship, child-to-parent, parent

We have a custom object (domain) with subscription dates.

I'd like to have a field on the account object but bring in the subscription date from each domain that is associated with the account.

Ie:
Account date field - 09/01/2020, 09/02/2020
subscription from domain 1 date field - 09/01/2020
subscription from domain 2 date field - 09/02/2020

Comment: If the number of custom object children is open ended you could end up with a long text string containing all the dates. What business need is driving this? An alternate approach is to use [two rollup summary fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&type=5) on Account to present the min and max dates.

Comment: That's what i recommended.  We have a team using totango and our child object is the teams "parent" object, if that makes sense.

Comment: DLRS can rollup and concatenate text values into the Account